# Return passing status on Github workflow when using paths-ignore

Tags: github-actions

I'm using a Github workflow to run tests. Because the setup can take a while, we want to skip running the tests when no code was changed.  So we are using `paths-ignore` like this:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
    paths-ignore:
      - '*.md'
```

The problem is that we have a protected branch here that *requires* a check to pass before a branch can be merged. There seems to be some workarounds  https://github.community/t/feature-request-conditional-required-checks/16761/20 but they are pretty clunky. Is there an elegant and idiomatic way to return a passing status here for a job that was essentially skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elegant and idiomatic, evidently not. The conclusion elsewhere ([GitHub community forum](https://github.community/t/unable-to-merge-pull-request-due-to-branch-protection-rules-since-github-actions-check-doesnt-trigger/126250/3), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/m9zvus/help_using_workflows_status_checks_and_pathsignore/)) is that this is expected behavior, at least right now.

The two main workarounds people seem to be using are:

- Run all required status checks on all PRs, even the slow ones. Sigh.
- Use [paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) or a homegrown alternative ([example](https://github.com/android-password-store/Android-Password-Store/commit/0c45bffaba1192ea8a10173e709f439dbf32b089#diff-87ee5504a3e25ac558b343724c905f2f7949e8cec3d92b9c4300bb922afa164f)) *inside* the required workflows, as part of their execution, and skip the actual work and return success if no relevant files were changed.